# Use of the solid angle in deriving the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, coordinate-systems

This is from a course in statistical mechanics, specifically the derivation of the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. We have an integral over the momentum space

$$Z = \frac{V}{(2\pi \hbar )^3}\int d^3p \exp\left({-\frac{mv^2}{2k_b T}}\right)$$

where the volume element becomes

$$d^3p=m^3d^3v=m^3v^2dv\ d\Omega$$

and the calculation proceeds from there. What I do not understand is the step from $d^3v$ to $v^2dv\ d\Omega$. Why are we allowed to change $dv$ to $v$ in this case? I assume this is some mathematical trick that comes up a lot that I've just never encountered before. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's basically a transformation from Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates.

Comment: Oh, in this case are we making the volume element $v dv*vd\Omega$? Are we not losing a dimension in this case? Or is $\Omega$ 2-dimensional?

Comment: $\omega$ is 2 dimensional, it consists of $\theta$ and $\phi$. See the Wikipedia page on spherical coordinates for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d^3v$ is a small "volume" element in 3-dimensional velocity space.

The most straight-forward to divide the velocity space
would be to use cartesian velocity coordinates $(v_x,v_y,v_z)$.
Then a "volume" element in velocity space is just a small cuboid
with volume
$$d^3v=dv_x\ dv_y\ dv_z.$$

Another way (and your course used that way) to divide the velocity space
is to use spherical coordinates $(v,\theta,\varphi)$.
Then a volume element looks like the green block in the image below:

[image]
<sub>(image from [Wikimedia - Volume element spherical coordinates](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Volume_element_spherical_coordinates.JPG))</sub>

It is a small part of a thin spherical shell.
The radius of this shell is $v$. 
Its thickness is $dv$.
The solid angle in this case is $d\Omega=\sin\varphi\ d\theta\ d\varphi$.
Then, by the [definition of solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Definition_and_properties),
its area (perpendicular to the thickness $dv$) is $dA=v^2 d\Omega$.
So finally the volume is
$$d^3v=dv\ dA=v^2 dv\ d\Omega.$$

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clear answer. Any idea why we would want to use the differential volume in this form instead of in cartesian coordinates, as is usually done when computing partition functions in the momentum space?

Comment: @Clerni Using the differential volume element in spherical coordinates 
makes it easier to actually calculate the integral:
$$\iiint \exp({-mv^2/2k_b T}) v^2\ dv\ d\Omega=
\int \exp({-mv^2/2k_b T}) v^2\ dv \iint d\Omega $$